# Capture el mensaje editado/actualizado del bot de Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

Me alegro de saludarlos, estoy implementando un user bot con python para telegram, funciona con la excepción de lo siguiente:

¿Cómo capturo los mensajes que se editan o actualizan en un determinado grupo de Telegram?

Hay grupos que implementan bots que responden con información según lo que se les pide.

Estos bots primero envían un mensaje de espera como:

> Espere mientras se consulta su información...

luego edita o actualiza ese mismo mensaje colocando el tipo de resultado:

> Gracias por esperar El BitCoin varió a: 0.1% Demora: 3.14's

Para lo cual no puedo encontrar una solución porque solo toma el primer mensaje:

> (Por favor espere mientras se consultan sus datos...)

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Este es un fragmento de mi código:

```html
   Send1 = x   # Grupo donde se enviaran los mensajes
   Group1 = x  # Grupo1  donde se tomaran los mensajes
   Group2 = x  # Grupo2  donde se tomaran los mensajes

client = TelegramClient('none', api_id, api_hash) 
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()
    chat_id = event.chat_id
    print(chat_id)`

   if chat_id == Group1 or chat_id == Group2: 
        await client.send_message(Send1, event.raw_text)
```

Intenté establecer time sleep pero no es el más adecuado y no funcionó como realmente quería.

Comment: Probaste con capturar el evento [messageEdited](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/events.html#telethon.events.messageedited.MessageEdited) y averiguar si el que editó el mensaje es un bot?

Comment: Sí, lo hice, pero por alguna razón no toma ningún mensaje.

Y si, el bot de los grupos suele demorar unos segundos dependiendo la consulta que se realice.

Algunas veces edita o actualiza el mismo mensaje creando un efecto de barra de progreso que oscila entre 30% 60% 90% "mensaje final = respuesta"

Estoy segura de que "no" elimina el mensaje y envía otro al instante. 
Lo actualiza o edita aunque no dice en el chat.

Comment: Encontre esto, ojala te ayude. Buscaré mas info https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/1244

Answer (score 1):

Resuelto!

Después de realizar una lectura exhaustiva de la documentación de [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/events.html#telethon.events.messageedited.MessageEdited) puede consolidar la siguiente solución:

```
@client.on(events.MessageEdited)
async def handler(event):
    print('Message', event.id, 'changed at', event.date, 'Test', event.raw_text)
```

P.D: No resuelve del todo el inconveniente; sin embargo, es aceptable.
Confió en que se puede mejorar.

Comment: Me habías dicho que habías intentado con messageEdited. Por curiosidad, cual es la diferencia entre mi propuesta y tu respuesta? Además, que cosa no se resuelve?

Comment: Amigo, realmente fuiste de ayuda, lo que respondí antes fue por una repuesta que realizaste o quiza fue otro usuario, pero estoy casi segura que fuiste tú, pero luego creo que la borraste. En fin... Copie tu código y lo implemente, pero no me funciono, eso fue lo que quise decir.

El problema que presentó es que me lleno del mismo mensaje, literal, cada actualización de un mismo mensaje son 9 que se envían.  Coloque lo que recomendaste en el código que eliminaste await asyncio.sleep(6)  y mi error fue colocar time.sleep, aunque aun sigo sin entender del todo el porque no funciona igual.

Comment: Si, fue mi respuesta xD me alegro de que te orientara. Lamentablemente, creo que no respondía la pregunta, ya que estaba orientada a editar un mensaje enviado por tu propio bot (imitar el funcionamiento de otros bots). Quizá por eso no funcionó como esperaba y es por eso que la eliminé. Si tu pregunta era como editar un mensaje enviado previamente por tu bot, tendré un motivo para volver a hacer visible la respuesta. Sobre el error que mencionas, ni idea de por que sea. Sinceramente, ni siquiera tengo telegram, respondí puramente en base a la documentación.

Comment: Haré otra pregunta similar, me gustaría que la respondieras para darte esa calificación que mereces.

Comment: Gracias! Pero no quiero presionarte ni nada, ni quiero ganar reputacion egoistamente. Así que si lo vas a hacer, que no sea puramente por mi.

Comment: Qué genial eres!!

Comment: Muchas gracias por el halago c: